# Exporting a multiple project query from TFS to Project? 

Tags: gantt, tfs, multi-projects

In my company most of the projects are within the same TFS (team system) team-project. Though a more general overview is necessary for execs or cross-application services (IT, DBA and such).

Oh, and we need to see that in MPP Gantt chart. If I'm trying to export to project a multi-project query (i.e. a DBA that takes part in all team projects)- it does not allow.

Can anyone advise/assist?

Comment: Does the software have an export feature where you can get at the raw data?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? Also, what process template are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is not possible pull in a query that goes across multiple team projects into MS Project with TFS today.

One workaround -- is to create a project plan and then add sub-project plans (the individual plans that are connected to the team projects) and form a "master plan".  This can act as a high-level report that you can share with the executives.  You can find the option to insert one plan into another from the Insert menu.

Hope that helps,
-Siddharth